# Disable autofill username & password on drupal

Tags: 7

How can tell the browser not to save drupal usrrname and password? I am newbie. So having difficulty understand many functions. Any easy way to configure drupal for this? Thanks

Comment: This is not a drupal question.. This is a default behavior of browsers.

Comment: Hello. This is off-topic here, as general HTML / JS question. Unless you know how to do that in pure HTML+JS. If you do, tell us how and we can tell you how to implement it in Drupal.

Comment: did you try this module? https://www.drupal.org/project/no_autocomplete

Answer (score 3):

Auto-completion of common fields (text, password, select, textarea, date-related, time-related, numeric, email, and uri controls) is a browser feature but you can tell browsers to turn off auto-completion on form fields by using the [autocomplete](http://www.w3.org/Submission/web-forms2/#the-autocomplete) attribute.

You can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to add this attribute to your fields.

Example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function example_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
    $form['YOUR_FIELD']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
  }
}
```

Example altering the log-in forms:

```
function example_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login_block': // Log-in block form.
    case 'user_login': // Log-in form.
      // Username
      $form['name']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';

      // Password
      $form['pass']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
      break;
  }
}
```

You can check out these posts for more info on module development - [Module Developer's Guide](https://drupal.org/developing/modules) and [Creating Drupal 7.x modules](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7). You can also download the excellent [Examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples) for reference.

Comment: Many Thanks. Say for example i want to disable the login username and password fields. Where/ in which file do i put the above code? Sorry, dont have any idea about drupal structure.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show an example that alters the log-in form.